# While controller is not working correctly

Tags: jmeter

On a http request, getting a task status as `ongoing` but want to run it in loop till it is `sucessful`. I am using while controller with a counter which is not working.

**http response**

```
{
    "data": {
        "uri": null,
        "taskId": "f5b6aaf3-8b14-49ba-a495-788eef5c523b",
        "taskStatus": "Ongoing"
    },
    "apiUrl": "http:\/\/imp-901v.pii.int:8081\/release01-nightly-api\/\/2192_IND_1_40",
    "statusCode": "102"
}
```

[image]

setting for while controller :
[image]

setting for counter:
[image]

transaction setting
[image]

user defined variable:
[image]

What I missed here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least following problems with your script:

1. You need to put `statsCounter` as the "Exported Variable Name" in the Counter (or just remove the counter and use `__jm__While Controller__idx` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) instead)
2. You need to change `props` to `vars`

   - `props` - is a shorthand for JMeter Properties
   - `vars` - is a shorthand for JMeter Variables

   More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thank Dmitri, Shall I remove the counter and what about the task_status check in the while controller ?

Comment: I would rather remove it as it's not needed in particular this use case, with regards to task_status check - make sure to extract this `taskStatus` value into `task_status` JMeter Variable using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) and ensure that it has the value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler), once you will get it - the condition should start working

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Beanshell Sampler / while controller/ if controller" has problem in JMeter 5.5. "if statement" in the samplers above don't work.

but Beanshell itself is ok

Evidence:
I put the same code in two sampler

1. BeanShelll Sampler still return 200

   Response code:200, Response message:OK
2. RSR223 Sampler     can   return 500 as wanted

   language setting: Beanshell(beanshell 2.0b6/BeanShell Engine1.0)

code:

```
String my_stauts = vars.get("status");

if (my_stauts.equals("a"))  {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Files are different");
}
```